# Another word or phrase for "foreign word"

Tags: single-word-requests, foreign-phrases

As an English-speaking American, what I would call a *foreign word* is not a foreign word to someone from another place who speaks another language. *Biblioteca* is a foreign word to me, but to a person from Mexico who speaks both Spanish and English, it isn't.

If that Spanish speaker is reading something I have written in English, and I have referred to *biblioteca* as a *foreign word*, I feel that's not quite right. Whether it's because I'm possibly thinking too literally or because using the term *foreign word* seems as though I might be treating the reader as part of an outgroup.

Is there another term I could use for this—preferably something more concise than "a word in a language other than the writer's native tongue"?

Comment: Can you not use "a Spanish word"?

Comment: Biblioteca is also an Italian word. You may probably use the expression  “ non-English word”.

Comment: I think you are overthinking this. Nobody reading a text in English is going to be confused or take offense, just the same as I don't take offense when I myself read a foreign text and find a reference to myself or my native language as foreign.

Comment: If a word is used occasionally and doesn't feel built-in, we can call it a *borrowed word*. If it's clearly Spanish or French by spelling or pronunciation, but standard in English, it's English though of that origin: casa, tortilla, detente, maitre d.

Comment: Everyone is correct! Thank you for humoring me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply say "the Spanish word *biblioteca*" or "the English term *library*", so you avoid completely the issue of the point of view and nationality of who is reading the text.

Comment: Man, I must have been having a rough day yesterday. That’s the answer I was looking for lol.